# SSL error only when running on systemd

Tags: systemd, ssl, openssl

I've posted a [broader question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250705/logstash-input-heroku-running-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-logstash-5-2-1) on StackOverflow but I think some of the issues are probably very ubuntu-specific.

I'm trying to run logstash on an aws ec2 instance running ubuntu 16.04 using systemd. Running the pipeline normally (via bin/logstash.bat) works fine and events are ingested.

But when I try to run the service on systemd I get errors, of which the first is an SSL error:

```
Error: no cipher match (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

[2017-02-15T13:08:44,037][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin
had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.   
Plugin:
<LogStash::Inputs::Heroku app=>"xxxxxx",
codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Multiline pattern=>"^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}
%{WORD}\\[\\w+(\\.\\d+)?\\]:(\\s{3,}| \\})", what=>"previous",
id=>"032c3b317ae49982945ec7e8fbf11224be98f237-3", enable_metric=>true,
negate=>false, charset=>"UTF-8", multiline_tag=>"multiline",
max_lines=>500, max_bytes=>10485760>,
id=>"032c3b317ae49982945ec7e8fbf11224be98f237-4", enable_metric=>true>
```

I've tried running the service as root but the result is the same. Just to clarify, this works:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash/
```

While this does not:

```
sudo systemctl start logstash
```

This is a clean install of logstash 5.2.1 following the [procedures on elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/installing-logstash.html). Systemd is also run according to [their procedures](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash.html), so that it executes the same command as I execute manually. `cat logstash.service` output:

```
[Unit]
Description=logstash

[Service]
Type=simple
User=logstash
Group=logstash
# Load env vars from /etc/default/ and /etc/sysconfig/ if they exist.
# Prefixing the path with '-' makes it try to load, but if the file doesn't
# exist, it continues onward.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/logstash
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/logstash
ExecStart=/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash "--path.settings" "/etc/logstash"
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/
Nice=19
LimitNOFILE=16384

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(result is the same when I comment out the user and group above)

---

EDIT:
So it seems like the SSL might be caused by the other error that I'm getting. I tailed both the journal of the service using `sudo journalctl -f -u logstash &` and the logs of the service itself in the background and got the following output:

> ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-216:~$ sudo systemctl start logstash
>
> ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-216:~$ Feb 15 15:38:19 ip-10-0-1-216 systemd[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250705/logstash-input-heroku-running-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-logstash-5-2-1):
>   Started logstash.
>
> Feb 15 15:38:33 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[5119]: Sending Logstash's logs
>   to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via log4j2.properties
>
> Feb 15 15:38:36 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[5119]: Enter your Heroku
>   credentials.
>
> Feb 15 15:38:36 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[5119]: Email: Password (typing
>   will be hidden):
>
> Feb 15 15:38:36 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[5119]: Enter your Heroku
>   credentials.
>
> Feb 15 15:38:36 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[5119]: Email: Password (typing
>   will be hidden):
>
> Feb 15 15:38:36 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[5119]: Enter your Heroku
>   credentials.
>
> Feb 15 15:38:36 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[5119]: Email: Password (typing
>   will be hidden):
>
> Feb 15 15:38:36 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[5119]: Enter your Heroku
>   credentials.
>
> Feb 15 15:38:36 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[5119]: Email: Password (typing
>   will be hidden):
>
> [2017-02-15T15:38:37,403][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin
>   had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.   Plugin:
>   "ros-prd",
>   codec=>"^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}
>   %{WORD}\[\w+(\.\d+)?\]:(\s{3,}| \})", what=>"previous",
>   id=>"9fd55a86d7f6e98e9c1698eb67a66a24364ea902-3", enable_metric=>true,
>   negate=>false, charset=>"UTF-8", multiline_tag=>"multiline",
>   max_lines=>500, max_bytes=>10485760>,
>   id=>"9fd55a86d7f6e98e9c1698eb67a66a24364ea902-4", enable_metric=>true>

So it looks like the SSL error only starts after the prompts to enter the heroku password.

So my question(s):

1. It looks like the heroku credentials are stored in ~/home/user/.netrc. **How can I provide the systemd service with with access to this file so that it does not prompt for the heroku password?**
2. **Or, if the above is not possible, how can I pass the password to the service? Is there some way to leverage [systemd-tty-ask-password-agent](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent.html) perhaps?**

Comment: Your question is a variation of [Why do things run differently under system?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239). Please see the related linked to answer to see the possible reasons why your app is behaving differently under systemd.

Comment: Thank you @MarkStosberg, I understand what is causing the issues now. But I'm not sure about how to resolve the issue yet. I will start researching the different points mentioned in the post you linked, but if you or anyone have a clue as to how to provide to the systemd process the variables et al required for SSL, that would really help me :)

Comment: argh, I have no clue... any more specific suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `systemd` is prompting you for your password but you aren't usually prompted for your password, compare these two cases between your `system` environment and the shell environment:

1. Is `systemd` running as the same user that you use when successfully running the command in the shell?
2. When run via `systemd`, does the HOME environment variable match the value used in the shell? Set `Environment="Home=/home/youruser"` in your systemd Unit file if needed.

As mentioned in the linked ticket, the best solution is never to blindly try to dump all the environment variables from your CLI environment into the `systemd` environment.

The intent with `systemd` is to provide an isolated, specific environment to provide you reliable, reproducible results over time. To set it up, you must know which environment variables affect your application. This understanding is quite likely going to help your use and troubleshooting of the app later.

Your CLI environment changes over time is relatively "polluted" with a number of values that aren't related to the task you are trying to run. Dumping all those values into the `systemd` environment may feel like fast-fix, but creates unnecessary complexity and confusion about what variables are really affecting the application.

Comment: Finally, that resolved the issue. I'm not sure how the SSL error is related to the heroku credentials, but there you go. Thanks!